# Can't Access Factory Function (Undefined is not a function)

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to call the getStuff function from my controller, but I get an error in the console saying that "undefined is not a function". I'm trying to return JSON from the GET and then store it in a $scope variable.

```
app.factory('UserInfo', function($http) { 

var user = [];

return{
        getStuff: function(){
            user.push($http.get('api/users'));
            return user;
    },
        testPost: function(){
            return $http.post('api/users');
    }
};
```

});

The factory is hooked up to the controller as follows

```
.controller('TwitterController', function($scope, $q, $interval, UserInfo) {
```

and here's the $scope function I'm using to call the factory function

```
$scope.datapls = function() {
    UserInfo.getStuff().success(function(response){
      console.log(response);
      $scope.loaduser.push(response);
    });
}
```

Thanks! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're error refers to the `.success()` function - it doesn't exist.

It looks like you're trying to use promises. If that's the case, then you need to `return` the promise itself from your service.

Something like this (not tested, but an idea). You want to use the `$q` in your service, not your contorller.

The examples in the [$q on AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) section are great.

So by doing this, your controller doesn't have to wait around for the data. As soon as it's resolved

```
app.service('UserInfo', function($http, $q) {
        this.getStuff = function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('api/users').success(function(data, status) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(data, status) {
                deferred.reject(data);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
);
```

And in your controller you can do this:

```
  UserInfo.getStuff().then(function(dataFromService){
       // dataFromService is used in here..
       $scope.loaduser.push(dataFromService);
    }, function(error) {
     // the error will come in via here
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I read the $q documentation and adapted this to my code and it worked.

Comment: Excellent :-) it's a strange thing to get used to, promises, but the building blocks :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), $http in itself returns a promise, you can change your factory function in order to achieve what you trying to do:

```
app.factory('UserInfo', function($http) { 

return{
        getStuff: function(){
            return $http.get('api/users'));
    },
        testPost: function(){
            return $http.post('api/users');
    }
};
});
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.datapls = function() {
    UserInfo.getStuff().then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
      $scope.loaduser.push(response);
    });
}
```